# GitHub Action throws a "a sequence was not expected"

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I am trying to create a MegaLinter workflow.

According to the documentation, I should be able to use the following:

```yaml
ENABLE_LINTERS:  
- TERRAFORM_KICS
- TERRAFORM_TERRAFORM_FMT
- TERRAFORM_TERRAGRUNT
- TERRAFORM_TERRASCAN
- TERRAFORM_TFLINT
```

Some google searching lead to the possible fix of removing the '-' but this just causes MegaLinter to not include any linters.

I am expecting the workflow file to load and run the Linters that have been enabled.

Comment: Hi! From the look of the configuration (https://megalinter.io/latest/configuration/), looks like you're using the correct syntax but you're still getting an error. Please include all the relevant information e.g. complete workflow to reproduce this, etc. to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax seems ok. You may try to indent by adding 2 spaces before the '-' but it will probably change nothing. Please could you share your entire .mega-linter.yml , and your github workflow running megalinter (probably .github/workflows/megalinter.yml ?

Comment: If indentation didn't work, can you share the remaining workflow? Probably there's an error elsewhere? I had this error when a comma-separated string was expected and I provided a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it:

I was actually putting the env variables directly in the `mega-linter.yml` and not the `.mega-linter.yml`. See https://github.com/taxonomicallyinformedannotation/tima-r/commit/ce637894329fd0188a048c44a3393a12d70f3f8d for more details

Hope this helps!